# How can I combine two regular expressions

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have two regular expressions. When I run them sequentially I get the desired result.

For this text

```
=IF((IF(EOMONTH(Trigger_Hires!$AA$15,0)>AD$7,0,IF(Trigger_Hires!$AC29=0,0,IF(Trigger_Hires!$AB29="$ Rev"
```

the first regular expression, in addition to selecting the range values, 
[image]
 is selecting Rev at the end.  If I then run the 2nd regular expression as a second step that term is not selected. My question is can I combine the regular expressions so that I don't have to have 2 steps?  TIA.

```
    function getPrecedents(thisFormula){

    var exp = /(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\()\b/gm;
    var results=[];
    var result;

    while ((result=exp.exec(thisFormula))!== null){
      if (!/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(result[0])) 
        results.push(result[0]); }
     return results;
    }
```

Comment: Try `/(\w+\!)?\$?[A-Z]{1,}(?:\d+)?(\:?\$?\w+)*(?!\(|")\b/gm`

Comment: @TheMaster  That worked!. Thank you